# Set Value and Position of Range Slider with Ionic

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework, cross-platform

Hy, 
I am using the Ionic Framework for App Development and i would like to track the time of a song with a [Range Slider](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#range). I can see the value changes correctly int the developer tools, but the value gets not applied to the visual representation of the slider. Is it even possible to do that?
part of my js code so far:

```
var duration, playerWasPaused;
var blockSeek = false;
var player;
var seekBar;
var url = 'http://xx.mp3';

function init(){

  console.log('Init');
  player = new Audio();
  player.src = url3;
  player.oncanplay = PreparePlay;
  player.volume = 0.2;
  player.currentTime = 0;

  seekBar = $('#playerRange');
  player.play();
}

function PreparePlay(){
  $("#playerRange").attr("min", 0);
  $("#playerRange").attr("max",player.duration);

  if(seekBar){
    createSeekBar(player, seekBar);
  }
}

function createSeekBar(seekBar){

  player.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', enableDisableSeekBar, false);
  player.addEventListener('emptied', enableDisableSeekBar, false);
  player.addEventListener('timeupdate', onTimeupdate, false);

  player.addEventListener('input', onSeek, false);
  player.addEventListener('change', onSeekRelease, false);

  enableDisableSeekBar();
  onTimeupdate();
}

function enableDisableSeekBar(){
  duration = player.duration;
  if(duration && !isNaN(duration)){
    seekBar.max = duration;
    seekBar.disabled = false;
  } else {
    seekBar.disabled = true;
  }
}

function onSeek(){
  if(!blockSeek){
    blockSeek = true;
    playerWasPaused = player.paused;
    player.pause();
  }
  player.currentTime = seekBar.value;
}

function onSeekRelease(){
  if(!playerWasPaused){
    player.play();
  }
  blockSeek = false;
}

function onTimeupdate(){

  if(!blockSeek){
    seekBar.attr("value", player.currentTime);
  }
}
```

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/MfLrW/

Comment: yes it is, also post some code if you look for a more specific answer

Comment: I added the code part of the player init and handling.

Comment: try `$scope.$apply()` at the end of your `PreparePlay()` function

Comment: Sadly this doesn't make a difference. Here is the code, i'm refferencing to: http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/MfLrW/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this call

```
seekBar.val(player.currentTime);
```

in the onTimeupdate.